# C# Error "Not supported by language" CS0570

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I was trying to add a new project to my solution, and when I added the reference to the main project it showed me this error:

```
Error   CS0570  'Logger.Debug(LogSource, string, params ?)' is not supported by the language
```

(this error is also shown for "Info " and"warn" parts in the following code)

and this is the part of the code for this error(in the new project with a reference to the old one):

```
namespace Logger
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleLogger clogger = new ConsoleLogger();

            FileLogger<LockedLogWriter> errorLogger = new FileLogger<LockedLogWriter>(
                CsvLogFormatter.Instance,
                new PrivacyScrubber(PhoneNumberScrubber.Instance, IDScrubber.Instance, FullNameScrubber.Instance),
                new IncrementalLogFileName(@"c:\log", "a13_error", CsvLogFormatter.Instance.FileExtention),
                LogLevels.ErrorOnly,
                LogSources.All,
                true);

            FileLogger<LockedLogWriter> allLogger = new FileLogger<LockedLogWriter>(
                CsvLogFormatter.Instance,
                new PrivacyScrubber(PhoneNumberScrubber.Instance, IDScrubber.Instance, FullNameScrubber.Instance),
                new IncrementalLogFileName(@"c:\log", "a13_all", CsvLogFormatter.Instance.FileExtention),
                LogLevels.All,
                LogSources.All,
                true);

            //esm,shomare melli hazf
             FileLogger<LockedLogWriter> PhoneLogger = new FileLogger<LockedLogWriter>(
                CsvLogFormatter.Instance,
                new PrivacyScrubber(IDScrubber.Instance, FullNameScrubber.Instance),
                new IncrementalLogFileName(@"c:\log", "a13_EShazf", CsvLogFormatter.Instance.FileExtention),
                LogLevels.All,
                LogSources.All,
                true);

            //Client
            FileLogger<LockedLogWriter> ClientLogger = new FileLogger<LockedLogWriter>(
                CsvLogFormatter.Instance,
                new PrivacyScrubber(PhoneNumberScrubber.Instance, IDScrubber.Instance, FullNameScrubber.Instance),
                new IncrementalLogFileName(@"c:\log", "a13_Client", CsvLogFormatter.Instance.FileExtention),
                LogLevels.All,
                LogSources.Create(LogSource.Client),
                true);

            FileLogger<LockedLogWriter> uiLogger = new FileLogger<LockedLogWriter>(
                CsvLogFormatter.Instance,
                new PrivacyScrubber(PhoneNumberScrubber.Instance, IDScrubber.Instance, FullNameScrubber.Instance),
                new IncrementalLogFileName(@"c:\log", "a13_ui", CsvLogFormatter.Instance.FileExtention),
                LogLevels.All,
                LogSources.Create(LogSource.UI),
                true);


            Logger.Loggers.Add(errorLogger);
            Logger.Loggers.Add(allLogger);
            Logger.Loggers.Add(clogger);
            Logger.Loggers.Add(uiLogger);
            Logger.Loggers.Add(PhoneLogger);
            Logger.Loggers.Add(ClientLogger);

            // Logger is set up and ready to use

            Logger.Instance.Debug(LogSource.UI, "Login button clicked");
            Logger.Instance.Debug(LogSource.Client, "User logged in", ("Name", "Mr. Ali Hassan"));
            Logger.Instance.Debug(LogSource.UI, "Add phone number cliecked");
            Logger.Instance.Info(LogSource.Client, "User number added", ("Name", "Mr. Ali Hassan"), ("PhoneNumber", "+98 21 2543331"));
            Logger.Instance.Debug(LogSource.UI, "Add national ID cliecked");
            Logger.Instance.Warn(LogSource.Client, "User national ID added", ("ID", "232-12-1212"));
            Logger.Instance.Debug(LogSource.UI, "Display error to user");
            Logger.Instance.Error(LogSource.Client, "Unable to add user", ("ID", "232-12-1212"));
        }

        private static void Debug_onlog(LogEntry entry)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and also I have already installed that System.ValueTuple package

does this need another package?

Comment: [Error CS0570](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0570) "This error occurs when using imported metadata that was generated by another compiler. Your code attempted to use a class member that the compiler cannot process."

Comment: Looks like you are adding a reference to an assembly that uses [params argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) in a function. But doing it from an old .NET Framework that does not support it. Youd should consider using a more recent .NET Framework version in your project.

Comment: thank you @bradbury9 it solved when I upgraded my .NET version

Comment: Glad to help, as long as it seems to be that the problem I have added my workaround as an answer. For the ValueTuple thing, if is stilll giving you trouble, maybe you should creating a new question with that problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are adding a reference to an assembly that uses [params argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) in a function. But doing it from an old .NET Framework that does not support it. Youd should consider using a more recent .NET Framework version in your project